# not able to install B2B extension for magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento2, extensions, b2b

I m using Magento 2.2.0 and trying to install B2B extension via composer require.

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                    
  Could not find package magento/extension-b2b at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-  
  stability
```

I used following link.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions/b2b-installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you purchased the extension from you Magento MarketPlace account.

If that's not the case make sure that your username and password are correct in the `auth.json`.

Reference: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/http-basic-authentication.md

Comment: I have given the Public Key as username and Private Key as a password in auth.json. Still, it's showing the same error. Any other suggestion? or how to check my access key having privileges.

Comment: It should be your actual username and password from the market place. Have a look at the link I added to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in your question! you shared [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions/b2b-installation.html) how to install B2B in magento commerce.

In documentation there mentioned **If you get an error when trying to install the B2B module for local instance of Magento Commerce (for example:)**

> [InvalidArgumentException] Could not find a matching version of package magento/extension-b2b. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

The same error you showing in your question and also give solution for it.

1. Create an auth.json file in the Magento root directory and add the following code. using the actual values of you `public_key` and `private_key` for username and password:

   `{
   "http-basic": {
     "repo.magento.com": {
        "username": "<public_key>",
        "password": "<private_key>"
     }
   }
   }`
2. When prompted, enter your authentication keys. Your public key is your username; your private key is your password. If you have stored your public and private keys in auth.json, you won’t be asked to enter them here.
3. Run the following commands after Composer finishes updating modules:

> bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

**Important**
After completing the installation, you must follow the [post-installation steps.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions/b2b-installation.html#configure-b2b)

**For your knowledge**

There are different process to install B2B module in `Magento commerce` and `Magento commerce cloud` please refer below process to install. please follow below given documentation link.

1. For Magento commerce refer this [Link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/install-extensions/b2b-installation.html)
2. For Magento commerce cloud refer [Link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/configure/setup-b2b.html)

I hope it helps!